# SSRS Lookups - Performance issue

Tags: function, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, lookup

The SSRS report is running for hours and not returning anything. I investigated and found that the report is using too many lookup functions in multiple datasets and that is causing the performance issue.
Can you please let me know how do I avoid those lookups from multiple dataset within one report ?

Comment: Unfortunately, the only way around using Lookups is to add the data to the datasets' queries. That said, hours seems like a long time - are you sure there's no other problems? How many different lookups are there, like 5 or a crazy amount like 50?

Comment: @HannoverFist, I would say, definetly there are 20+